# WP_Error not displaying errors

Tags: pre-get-posts, wp-error

I am trying to utilize WP_Error for my plugin, but nothing happens. Is this too late for WP_Error? Too early? Or am I doing something else wrong?

```
function cpt_pre_post_publish(){
    return new WP_Error('error', __('Error!' ));
}

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'cpt_pre_post_publish');
```

Comment: All you're doing is `return`ing the `WP_Error`. Do you try to display it somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actions don't typically `return` data, so I doubt you will get this working the way you are trying to. Something like...

```
function cpt_pre_post_publish(){
  global $my_error;
  $my_error = new WP_Error('error', __('Error!' ));
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'cpt_pre_post_publish');
```

... should set a variable that you could access in a template file with...

```
global $my_error;
var_dump($my_error);
```

It is really not clear exactly what you are trying to do though.

Comment: I thought if I returned a WP_Error object in a hook then Wordpress would display it itself, but that is clearly not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Please see [the example on the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Error#Example), which indicates that you can return the WP_Error from a function, later use the function `is_wp_error()` (essentially the same as checking `instanceof WP_Error`), and display the error message.

s_ha_dum is right that actions shouldn't really return -- there's nothing to catch the information being returned.